# Doble datos en un grid Progamacion Web

Tags: asp.net, web, aplicación-web

Soy nuevo en programacion web y queria saber porque cuando llamo mi informacion a un grid me sale doble los datos, ayuda porfaaa

[image: Asi me aparece]

[image: Este es el codigo]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no pongas una imagen de tu codigo, pega el codigo. y a que te referis con datos dobles? yo veo dos filas distintas...